# How to make a discord bot fetch nickname instead of username?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot for a server for a faction in a game. Everyone sets their nickname to their in game name but the `message.author` function fetches the users normal discord name. What function can i use to check for their nickname?

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `display_name`

```
nick = message.author.display_name
# It's the same as
nick = message.author.nick or message.author.name
```

Note: If the member doesn't have a nick, the name will be displayed